# Can't Dismiss Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

```
//About Button in the principal menu       
final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

button3.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {                
        //set up dialog
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainMenu.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
        dialog.setTitle("About");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
        dialog.show();

        Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
//      closeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 
//          public void onClick(View view) { 
//              dialog.dismiss();
//          }
//      });

        if(v==closeButton)
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

I have this code but the dismiss is not working.

I have an "about" button and when i click on in it shows the dialog window.
Then the dialog windows has a "OK" button and this OK button should dismiss the dialog but the dismiss is not working.
Could you help me to know why??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your Dialog needs to be in the scope of your class, so you need to declare

```
public Dialog dialog;
```

outside of any methods.  Then, in your `onCreate()` method, create the Dialog like you already have.  Leave just the `show()` and `dismiss()` calls to the OnClickListeners.

Your buttons would then look like:

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.show();
    }
});

Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Also, it's good to come up with a naming convention that works for you rather than randomly capitalizing or not capitalizing resource names (e.g., Button03 vs. button1);

Comment: Thanks for helping me Glendon Trullinger! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a common onClick for both the buttons like this. This will avoid the rewriting of onClick event for every button.It will become easy for maintenance.

public void onClick(View v) {

```
   switch(v.getId())
   {
       case R.id.button3:
           dialog.show();

       case R.id.Button01:
           dialog.dismiss();
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the Dialog outside the `OnClickListener`.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainMenu.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);

button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
       public void onClick(View v) {              
         dialog.show();    
       }
});

Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          dialog.dismiss();
       }
});
```